# Exclude one url from web security

Tags: spring-security

I have the following in my spring web security

```
        http
        .headers()
    .and()
        .sessionManagement()
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/info").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
```

Which works fine except for I have one url which I want to allow a permitAll on e.g. /api/state/???

I have tried a few things which do not work (authentication fails) e.g.

```
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
            .antMatchers("/api/state/**").permitAll();
```

What I am looking for is a way to add an exclude to the following

```
.antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
```

I want to avoid listing all urls under api and setting them to authenticated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is in order of rules. You should first declare `permitAll` rules:

```
    .antMatchers("/api/state/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
```

Comment: Actually, the order of the rules must go from most specific to less. If you declare first `"/api/**"` , urls starting with `/api/state/` would match `"/api/**"` so the rules for the antMatcher `"/api/state/**"` will not be applied

Comment: that did not work. The answer from borino worked fine